# Print list of contacts starting with '+55'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to list my WhatsApp contacts that start with the name +55

Below is a sketch of code that I was able to come up with but without success:
Can you help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Crie uma instância do webdriver do Chrome
navegador = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navegue até o WhatsApp Web
navegador.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')


time.sleep(30)  # aguarde 5 segundos antes de tentar encontrar o elemento
conversas = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pane-side"]')


contacts_list = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pane-side"]')
contacts = navegador.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[13]/div/div/div/div[3]')

# filtre a lista de contatos para obter apenas aqueles que começam com +55
filtered_contacts = [contact for contact in contacts if contact.text.startswith('+55')]

# imprima os nomes dos contatos filtrados
for contact in filtered_contacts:
    print(contact.text)

navegador.quit()
```

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt? Can you specify what "without success" means?

Comment: It means that it is not listing all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work but it doesn't seem to bring up all the numbers in the list.

I repeat, it is working but without listing all the contacts in the contact list.
I would like to get the complete list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Caminho para o driver do Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Acessa o WhatsApp Web
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')

# Espera até que o QR code seja escaneado
input("**** Aperte Enter após escanear o QR code ****")

time.sleep(120)  # aguarde 30 segundos antes de tentar encontrar o elemento

# Encontra todos os contatos
contacts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div')

# Encontra todos os elementos com o atributo "title"
#elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title]')
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ggj6brxn')

# Itera sobre os elementos e imprime o título de cada um
for element in elements:
  print(element.get_attribute("title"))

# Itera sobre os contatos e imprime o título de cada um
###for contact in contacts:
###  print(contact.get_attribute("title"))

# Fecha o navegador
driver.quit()
```